# PostgreSQL Client Certificate TLS error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, ssl

- PostgreSQL 9.4.6
- OpenSSL 1.0.2f

If my server or client certificate use SHA256, I get the following error on the client:

```
psql: SSL error: tlsv1 alert decrypt error
```

And the following log message on the server:

```
LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: unknown message digest algorithm
```

If I generate the client key with SHA1, it works fine:

```
openssl x509 -req -in user.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey server.key -out user.crt -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha1
```

How can I get it to work with SHA256?

Comment: Do you set [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) correctly? If this file is set correctly, i think it is a problem of openssl library, because the log message `unknown message digest algorithm` is written by ssl lib.

Comment: Yes if I use sha1 certs without changing `pg_hba.conf` it works fine.

Comment: Here is the source code of [postgres](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ee943004466418595363d567f18c053bae407792/src/backend/libpq/be-secure-openssl.c). line 390 generates your log message. More precisely, `SSLerrmessage` (line 958) creates that message by calling the openssl's function `ERR_reason_error_string`.  Therefore postgres only returns the openssl's error message. On the other words, (i think) the problem has occured on the openssl layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if PostgreSQL is compiled against an older version of openssl than the version used to generate the keys.

Recompiling with the correct openssl library fixes the problem.